# How to iterate through all the lines using my regex from csv?

Tags: python, csv, python-re

I want to iterate through all the processes using my regex, but I don't know how to do it properly.

```
import csv
import re

matched_dynamic_pattern = []
matched_static_pattern = []
not_matched = set()

with open('processes.csv', 'r') as t1, open('dynamic_patterns.csv', 'r') as t3:
    commands = set()
    reader = csv.DictReader(t1, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        commands.add(row['Command Line'])
    dynamic_patterns = set(t3.read().splitlines())

for command in commands:
    for pattern in dynamic_patterns:
        if re.search(pattern, command): #MY PATTERN IS NOT WORKING FROM dynamic_patterns.csv
            matched_dynamic_pattern.append(command)
        else:
            if command not in dynamic_patterns:
                not_matched.add(command)
```

`dynamic_patterns.csv` contain only one regex: `r'\"C:\\Program\sFiles\s\(x\d\d\)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"\s--type'` that should match `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --type` in `processes.csv`
But there will be a lot of regex and I don't know how to make a solution on technical level.

Answer (score 0):

The example regex you have above does not work.  I think there is an errant " in the pattern towards the end.

Below works with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --type"

```
\"C:\\Program\sFiles\s\(x\d\d\)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\s--type
```

Tested on [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Do you have any more examples of patterns?

Comment: I misspelled. The pattern without `"` in the end.
https://i.imgur.com/ulWmCIG.png

Comment: So, the pattern is ok, but how to put my regex into the loop with re.search?